# how to use substr with get_the_content()

Tags: filters, content

I'm setting og:description programmatically like this:

`$description = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );`

This works fine.

However, the **$description** contains some superfluous content which I'm trying to remove. When I do this it never seems to work. This is what I'm trying:

```
$pos = strpos( $description, $superfluous_content ) + strlen( $superfluous_content );
$description = substr( $description, $pos );
```

I've tried removing html tags and all kinds of different approaches, but it never makes a difference. I'm guessing **$description** contains some kind of hidden characters as **$pos** always returns 0.

Can anyone suggest what's happening here and how I can manipulate **$description** as a simple text string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need an excerpt for the tag, have you tried using `get_the_excerpt`? What is the superfluous content variables contents?

Comment: If you know what the `$superfluous_content` string is, why not use [`str_replace()`](https://php.net/str_replace): `$description = str_replace( $superfluous_content, '', $description );`

Comment: LOL, get_the_excerpt worked perfectly and I'm an idiot for not trying that earlier! Thanks!

Comment: But... as an academic exercise, I wonder why strpos (or str_replace) won't work with the content.